# Calculations within SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

**I am looking for answers that are valid on SQL SERVER 2000 please!**
I have a table in SQL that is like

```
                         Jan hours  
    Employee 1 Regular      10
    Employee 1 Overtime     10
    Employee 1 Vacation     1
    Employee 2 Regular      15
    Employee 2 Overtime     15
    Employee 2 Vacation      1
```

What would be the SQL query so that there would be entries, in the same table for ONLY regular and overtime hours? So the next two entries in the same table would look like

```
    Emplpyee 1 Total     20
    Emplpyee 2 Total     30
```

Comment: You should specify your columns to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Can you help me better undersand wha you mean by " So the next two entries in the same table would look like".. Are you talking about inserting tuples back into the table? Or are you talking about the query results?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know your column names or even the table structure but you can use the following which uses an aggregate function and a `GROUP BY`:

```
select emp, sum(hours) Total
from yourtable
where type in ('Regular', 'Overtime')
group by emp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dca39/2)

If your data is not normalized and the employee and type are in the same column, then you can use something like this:

```
select 
  replace(replace(emp, 'Regular', ''), 'Overtime', '') Emp,
  sum(hours) total
from yourtable
where emp like '%Regular%'
  or emp like '%Overtime%'
group by replace(replace(emp, 'Regular', ''), 'Overtime', '')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12135/11)

Comment: +1 but not clear to me whether the source data is normalized (e.g. are `emp` and `type` really separate columns?).

Comment: I agree, I am just guessing at this point.  They need to provide more details.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Added a version if it is not normalized. I don't have a SQL Server 2000 instance to test on, but I think it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    left(EmpName, 11) + ' Total',
    SUM(hours)
from 
    emptab
WHERE
    hourstype in ('Regular', 'Overtime')
group by
    EmpName
```

Comment: Why `left(EmpName, 11)`? Do you think all employees are named with the same pattern? And if you are trying to take 'regular', 'overtime' etc. out of the employeename, you aren't cutting off at the right spot, and this seems to conflict with your where clause, which assumes the hourstype value is in a separate column, not appended to the name,

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I was probably being too literal with his given data (where all employees began with "employee").  I did assume that hourstype was a separate column, but it is difficult to tell from the example given.